# Why does my AWS Codestar application endpoint not show code changes?

Tags: aws-codestar

I made my first Codestar project with the web service template for node and lambda.

I pushed code changes and all 3 steps finished green. I even checked Pipeline and the comment from my latest code push showed there. However, when I click on my endpoint in my dashboard (it ends in /Prod), it shows as if nothing happened. I'm still seeing the Hello World output from the project's original code.

Just as a guess, I clicked Release Change after this, and still no change.
It's been hours since I made the change. I am new and totally stumped.

Also, when I use AWS SAM to start a local endpoint, everything works perfectly. My newest changes appear, and all is good.

Why does my AWS Codestar application endpoint not show code changes?

Comment: EDIT: I found the source of the issue. I downloaded the lambda code from AWS Lambda, and it has never changed. It is still the original code. Why does this not update when I do a `git push`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be that the api is not being deployed. Whenever you make a change to Apigateway you have to re-deploy the api. Codestar should be doing that. You can go to the api itself in Apigateway and take a look at 'Stage'. There the deployed api url is shown.

Also, make sure your browser isn't caching the url.